# wicket MVC best practice

Tags: model-view-controller, wicket

Hi I'am working for sone time with wicket and in my team we argue a lot abot the place that should be given to the design

I think that design should be only in markup in order to achive separation of concernes where others think what i am doing is a boiling plat code

for example we are using this structure to support IE8 usung round corners with pictures :

```
<div class="panel-wrapper">
   <div class="panel-left"></div>
   <div class="panel-right"></div>
   <div class="panel-bottom"></div>
   <div class="panel-top"></div>
   <div class="panel-bottom-right"></div>
   <div class="panel-bottom-left"></div>
   <div class="panel-top-right"></div>
   <div class="panel-top-left"></div>
   <div class="panel-bg"></div>
   <div class="panel-body">
  //stuff 
 </div>
```

i think that allthoght it's against my belives as a developer this is the best way to achive mvc , to separate view from controler where others say that we should write this code once in wicket panel an derive from the wicket panel

what if tommarow this component would be in another place and the given markup would couse us problems such as using @override getVaration?

Comment: I would keep it in html. If you are worried about dupplication, try extraction common code into panels that wrap the actual content. Or even better, get rid of the IE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Behaviors?
Keep your component clean by putting the basic layout into the template but use AttributeAppender/AttributeModifiers to add CSS-Classes.

Comment: i think it's a bad idea , markup should b the view with his css , design , by using getVaration you can use two html for the same controler ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to allow designers (who should know about css and semantic markup) to create a static version of your page, then you can decide how to construct the panel and then "wicketize" your panel's markup. I think that's the role designers and developers can play.
Often when deciding how to create a panel, one might be concerned about "what if the markup changes"?.. Well, that's the reason why is useful to know the road map of your website and see how it can be reused. In my case, what I usually do is create an abstract panel with no markup and then start extending it, instead of creating styles and stuff like that, because that usually leads to changes in the panel every time you need a different style when you change the behavior of you panel depending on the style. If you think an abstract panel can be overkill, you can create a default panel with the markup that might get used the most and extend when necessary and use different markup for that new panel.